# Filter django models by field and include data with null field

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have the dataset where i need to fetch some articles by companies, but also in same query i need to fetch data which have company = null.

Basically fetch company = 1 or company = null

I tried something like this but filter does not recognize None and just skip.

```
# example 1
Article.objects.filter(company__in=[1, None])
```

I tried something like this and this works, but i need something like example above, because i have framework for filtering which takes dict as custom filters, so i need key value pairs.

```
# example 2
Article.objects.filter(Q(company_id=1) | Q(company=None))
```

Is there any way i achive something like example 1 or some similar solutions?

**EDIT**:

If im stuck with example 2 is there any way i can combine those two, i have something like this in my framework.

```
Article.objects.filter(**custom_filter)
```

custom filter is dict, for example i have currently

```
    custom_filter = {
        'app': 1,
        'company': 1
    }
```

Comment: Well an `in` lookup will not be possible because `null != null` (In fact `null = null`, `null != null`, `null in (null)` all return `null`) in SQL. You are unfortunately stuck with the second solution.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Is there any way i can combine those two examples, check out my edit.

Comment: But your `custom_filter` does not appear to have any `in` lookups? Can you give a more descriptive example of what exactly you want.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have a framework which do the filtering, basically i provide model, request filters and custom filters. Basically custom filters are something which is added to every query. And i have around 4-5 keys inside custom_filter dict. 

My problem is i need workaround to combine custom filters and example 2 query, or something like example 1.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 
Article.objects.filter(**custom_filter and Q(company_id=1) | Q(company=None))
Something like this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand you have a `custom_filter` this **does not** have an `in` filter (At least with null values?). And you also have a list of ids you want and perhaps you may or may not want null values too. You can do something like below, to make such queries:

```py
company_list = [1, 2, 3] # Don't put `None` here
nulls_needed = True # Change as per your need
custom_filter = {
    'app': 1,
}


Article.objects.filter(
    Q(company__isnull=nulls_needed) | Q(company__in=company_list), # positional args first
    **custom_filter # keyword args later
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use __isnull as shown

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(company_id=1) | Q(company__isnull=True))
```

Comment: Is there any way i can append more filters after

Comment: Yes, you can use operator._or to generate your query dynamically based on or